# How to use category slug to echo a page's content with the same slug

Tags: terms

How can I fit this category slug

`<?php $term = get_queried_object(); echo $term->slug; ?>`

into this page content
`<?php      $page = get_posts([ 'name'      => 'slug-goes-here', 'post_type' => 'page' ]); if ( $page ){    echo $page[0]->post_content;}  ?>`

Comment: What do you mean by "fit"? Also, Pages (post type `page`) by default do not have categories, so did you manually add the category taxonomy to the `page` post type? And by "category", are you referring to the default `category` taxonomy?

Comment: I'm using a category slug that has the same slug as a corresponding page. So when someone visits the post category archive I can display the contents of the page on the archive page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out...

```
<?php $term = get_queried_object(); ?>
<?php   
$page = get_posts([
    'name'      => $term->slug,
    'post_type' => 'page'
]);
if ( $page ){ echo $page[0]->post_content; }    
?>
```